# Snapchat API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I've looked at http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/

How would I go about implementing this in **Swift**?

I can store their credentials, and to get the snaps they received I can call `/bq/login` but I'm not sure how to get all the correct info needed to make the request. I can also call `/ph/blob` to get the blob. I just need assistance structuring the request.

I am mostly having trouble creating a request to Snapchat.

Here are the options used to make the token:

```
var options = ["blob_enc_key": "M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4", "pattern": "0001110111101110001111010101111011010001001110011000110001000110", "secret": "iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOk", "static_token": "m198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9", "url": "https://feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com", "user_agent": "Snapchat/8.1.1 (iPad; iPhone OS 6.0; en_US; gzip)"]
```

And the code to make the token:

```
func dualHash(_ value1: Data, andHash value2: Data) -> String {
    var s1: Data? = self.secret
    s1?.append(value1)
    var s2: Data? = value2
    s2?.append(self.secret)
    var s3: String = hexHash(s1)
    var s4: String = hexHash(s2)
    var pattern: String = options["pattern"]
    var result = String()
    for i in 0..<(pattern.characters.count ?? 0) {
        if pattern[i] == "0" {
            result += String(format: "%C", s3[i])
        }
        else {
            result += String(format: "%C", s4[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

This code doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I fixed it up. :)

Comment: As mentioned in the link you posted, there are several unofficial Snapchat API clients posted on Github. There are two in Objective C. Maybe you can use one of those directly or translate them to Swift? https://github.com/searchq=snapchat+API&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=✓

Answer (score 0):

All public Snapchat API wrappers are broken. Only one person has figured out how to access their API and he is privately selling access (proxying via his own API) and charges a few thousand dollars per month. I'm pretty sure it's [Liam Cottle](https://github.com/liamcottle).